# Inner product space expansions

Tags: inner-products

I would like to expand the following two:

i). $||v+w||^2$

ii). $||v-w||^2$

I know that $||v||=\sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$.

For (i) I would therefore have

$$||v+w||^2=\langle v+w,v+w\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle + 2\langle v,w\rangle +\langle w,w\rangle$$

and for (ii) I would have

$$||v-w||^2=\langle v-w,v-w\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle - 2\langle v,w\rangle +\langle w,w\rangle$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: $\| v+ w\|^2 = \langle v+ w, v+w \rangle$ where $\langle x, y\rangle$ denotes the inner product of $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

Norms and inner product are related by $||a||^2=\langle a, a\rangle$. So
\begin{align*}
||v+w||^2 &=\langle v+w, v+w\rangle\\
& = \langle v, v\rangle +\langle v, w \rangle +\langle w, v\rangle + \langle w, w\rangle
\end{align*}

Comment: Personally, I find using $\cdot$ to represent inner product is considered passe and confusing, as it is also used to represent the dot product specifically. I tend to use (and see people use) $\langle a,b\rangle$.

Comment: (you still get an up-vote, I just wanted to mention that fact)

Comment: Your last step is correct *only* if you assume this is a **real** linear space. For unitary ones it already is not correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio you are absolutely correct. My mistake, I assumed we are working over $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks.

Comment: @StellaBiderman point noted and edited accordingly.

Comment: @AnuragA what about the second case? On a problem sheet I am doing it is used as $<v,v>-<v,w>-<w,v>+<w,w>$ and I'm not sure why

Comment: @Leonhard In the second case you are replacing $w$ with $-w$ and then using property (e) as shown in Jack's answer.

Comment: @AnuragA makes sense, thank you.